# Swapping first and last items in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, swap

How can I go about swapping numbers in a given list?

For example:

```
list = [5,6,7,10,11,12]
```

I would like to swap `12` with `5`.

Is there an built-in Python function that can allow me to do that?

Comment: What specifies which elements you want to swap?  The values (replace every 12 with a 5 and every 5 with a 12), the positions (switch the values in the first and last place), or some other rule?  For example, what do you want to happen for `[5,5,12,12]`?

Comment: I would like the last number in the list to always be swapped with the first number in a list.... in any given list.

Answer (score 23):

```
>>> lis = [5,6,7,10,11,12]
>>> lis[0], lis[-1] = lis[-1], lis[0]
>>> lis
[12, 6, 7, 10, 11, 5]
```

[Order of evaluation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) of the above expression:

```
expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2
```

First items on RHS are collected in a tuple, and then that [tuple is unpacked](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and assigned to the items on the LHS.

```
>>> lis = [5,6,7,10,11,12]
>>> tup = lis[-1], lis[0]
>>> tup
(12, 5)
>>> lis[0], lis[-1] = tup
>>> lis
[12, 6, 7, 10, 11, 5]
```

Comment: hello ! Thanks for the prompt reply ! Could you please explain what is happening in this piece of Code... I am fairly new at programming.

Comment: @user2891763 I've added some explanation.

Comment: This swapping technique also works for `numpy.ndarray`

Answer (score 3):

you can swap using this code,

```
list[0],list[-1] = list[-1],list[0]
```

Comment: Yes. Also works the same for `numpy.ndarray`

Answer (score 3):

You can use "*" operator.

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a, *middle, b = my_list
my_new_list = [b, *middle, a]
my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
my_new_list
[9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
```

Read [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the index of the number you want to change.

```
In [38]: t = [5,6,7,10,11,12]

In [40]: index5 = t.index(5) # grab the index of the first element that equals 5

In [41]: index12 = t.index(12) # grab the index of the first element that equals 12

In [42]: t[index5], t[index12] = 12, 5 # swap the values

In [44]: t
Out[44]: [12, 6, 7, 10, 11, 5]
```

Then you can make a quick swapping function

```
def swapNumbersInList( listOfNums, numA, numB ):
    indexA = listOfNums.index(numA)
    indexB = listOfNums.index(numB)

    listOfNums[indexA], listOfNums[indexB] = numB, numA

# calling the function
swapNumbersInList([5,6,7,10,11,12], 5, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (not so cute):

```
mylist   = [5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12]
first_el = mylist.pop(0)   # first_el = 5, mylist = [6, 7, 10, 11, 12]
last_el  = mylist.pop(-1)  # last_el = 12, mylist = [6, 7, 10, 11]
mylist.insert(0, last_el)  # mylist = [12, 6, 7, 10, 11]
mylist.append(first_el)    # mylist = [12, 6, 7, 10, 11, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [5,2,3,6,1,12]
temp = ''
lastvalue = 5

temp = array[0]
array[0] = array[lastvalue]
array[lastvalue] = temp

print(array)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

## This is what finally worked for me.

```
def swap(the_list):
    temp = the_list[0]
    the_list[0] = the_list[-1]
    the_list[-1] = temp
    return the_list
```