# Best way to access last element of list in Kotlin

Tags: java, list, kotlin

Is there a way to access the last element of a `List` using a special index like in python where -1 return the last element? avoiding to write extra code like `list.size - 1`.
An example of the python way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666782/3466808).

I've tried following but doesn't work:

```
fun main() {
    val numbers = (1..5).toList()

    println(numbers[-1])
}
```

Any help or explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: In Java: `numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1)`. In Kotlin, I do not know.

Comment: what's wrong with `size - 1`? It's direct index too

Comment: @Sergey Glotov I want a more simpler like just `-1` in Python, just curious that if is it possible.

Comment: `numbers[numbers.lastIndex]` or `numbers.last()`, what you intend to use this for exactly?

Comment: Most languages, including Kotlin, don't have this notation. It's in Python and Perl. Kotlin is interoperable with Java, so it probably wasn't even an option to include it because of the behavior change. A negative index in Java will give you an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `numbers.lastIndex`:

```
fun main() {
    val numbers = (1..5).toList()
    println(numbers[numbers.lastIndex])
}
```